# Solution to cleaning cache after made changes on code?

Tags: javascript, php, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am new in the Field of web development, and now that I am working on personal projects, after a while, I need to clean the cache of the browsers to see if the changes I make to the code works, (I use CCleaner) I want to know if there is a faster way to do this and without closing all the application within the browser. Serious I am a new, so any help its appreciated.

Comment: Chrome > F12 (Dev Tools) > Go to Network Tab > Check "Disable Cache" > refresh

Comment: What platform are you developing on?

Comment: use Incognito window because Incognito window does not use cache.

Comment: Just press CTRL+F5.